# django ckeditor won't show the errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, ckeditor, django-ckeditor

I am using django-ckeditor package in my django project. These are my problems:

- **Ckeditor does not show any error when I leave the about_me field blank!** But it does not create a new object.
- Also when my text has tabs and spaces, **no object is **created** and it does not give any error!**

Here is my codes:

[view](https://github.com/parsa-rahbari-82/udemy_clone/blob/96b82c2cd6d856b2051789c8b522de0a623ba8bd/UdemyClone/requests/views.py#L9),

[template](https://github.com/parsa-rahbari-82/udemy_clone/blob/96b82c2cd6d856b2051789c8b522de0a623ba8bd/UdemyClone/requests/templates/requests/teaching-request.html),

[model](https://github.com/parsa-rahbari-82/udemy_clone/blob/96b82c2cd6d856b2051789c8b522de0a623ba8bd/UdemyClone/requests/models.py) and [form](https://github.com/parsa-rahbari-82/udemy_clone/blob/96b82c2cd6d856b2051789c8b522de0a623ba8bd/UdemyClone/requests/forms.py)

Comment: Please add your *related* code to the question itself!

Comment: I have put the link of all the codes.

Comment: i did not see any problem with your code, but maybe the problem is enctype, try to add enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute in your form. also add request.FILES in your form alongside request.POST in the view